# Hide specific attribute filters for each category

Tags: attributes, catalog, layered-navigation

i want to hide specific attribute filters for each one of my categories. Is that possible from category ->  custom design -> Custom Layout Update ?

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't hide specific attributes from the layered navigation using custom layout updates. At least not without any changes to the code (check out layer/view.phtml).

There are a few modules for a better layered navigation, and I know for sure [GoMage Advanced Navigation](https://www.gomage.com/gomage-advanced-navigation.html) has this feature.

I've also used custom code to filter out which attributes show up on certain categories and in what order - i think i used a helper and changed a few lines in layer/view.phtml. This would be pretty similar to using layout updates, although you might run into difficulties using the xml approach.

If you want to use custom code, I'd suggest adding an extra category attribute for setting the attributes that you want to hide and then using that field in layer/view.phtml.

Answer (score 2):

it is not possible using ustom layout.You can only buy using custom condition at layer/view.phtml

```
<?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>

    <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
    <?php  if($_filter->getFilter()->getRequestVar()):?>
    <?php if(isset(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()) && (Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId()!=youcatid)){ ?>
        <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
        <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

See at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862967/magento-get-selected-filter-in-layered-navigation